# Width of NSTextField inside NSTableCellView

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

I'm trying to create a very simple NSTableCellView with a textfield and a button. My code to layout the NSTableCellView is below. I want the textfield to have a width of 100px.

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    MyTableCellView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCellView" owner:self];

     if (cellView == nil) {
         cellView = [[MyTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(outlineView.bounds), [outlineView rowHeight])];

         NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, [outlineView rowHeight])];
         [cellView addSubview:textField];
         cellView.textField = textField;

         NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(108, 0, 50, [outlineView rowHeight])];
         [cellView addSubview:button];
         cellView.button = button;

         cellView.identifier = @"MyTableCellView";
     }

     cellView.textField.stringValue = item.stringValue;

     return cellView;
}
```

When I do this, however, the NSTextField takes up the entire row:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I didn't think twice about setting the NSTextField I created to the NSTableCellView's textfield outlet. It turns out this should not be done because then it is automatically resized.

So I took out this line and it works as expected:

```
cellView.textField = textField;
```